# OpenCL: pipes and custom types

Tags: struct, pipe, opencl, typedef

I am trying to use the new pipes features of OpenCL 2.0, but I can't get them to work with a custom data type of mine, that has been defined with a struct.

Does anyone know a workaround for using pipes and custom data types?

thanks

Comment: I am facing the same issue. An answer will be appreciated!